# Error Undefined class constant 'index' in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

I am Learning to use Laravel and I need help in the following problem
**Error
Undefined class constant 'index'**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TemplateController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
/*
Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
});*/


Route::get('/',TemplateController::index, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route should contain brackets, `::index` should be `::class` and the last `'/'` should be the method to be called. Change your route to:

```
Route::get('/', [TemplateController::class, 'index']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing